# Performing an audit using reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, reflection

I would like to perform an audit as part of a unit test that uses reflection to verify some assumptions, the basic-psuedo code for this would be as follows:

1. For each class in a given assembly,
   locate the controller classes
   (ASP.NET MVC2).
2. For each action in this class,
   locate any that are decorated with a
   given attribute (lets call this
   `TargetAttribute`)
3. For each of these methods decorated
   with the attribute of interest,
   ensure that at least one of the
   action method's parameters implements a given
   interface (let's call this
   `ITarget`).

How would I go about performing such a check? (answers in C# or VB.NET are welcome)

**Edit:**

I am posting the final code here (translated to VB.NET) that performs this check:

```
    Dim ass As Assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(GetType(Web.WebConfiguratorMarker))

    Dim methodsToCheck = ass.GetTypes().
                         Where(Function(t) t.IsSubclassOf(GetType(Controller))).
                         SelectMany(Function(t) t.GetMethods()).
                         Where(Function(m) m.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(AutoValidateJsonModelAttribute), False).Length > 0).
                         Where(Function(m) m.ReturnType Is GetType(ActionResult)).ToArray()

    For Each method In methodsToCheck

        Dim implementsIValidatable As Boolean = False

        For Each param In method.GetParameters()
            If GetType(IValidatable).IsAssignableFrom(param.ParameterType) Then
                implementsIValidatable = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        Assert.True(implementsIValidatable, String.Format("Controller of type [{0}] has an action [{1}] that is decorated with <AutoValidateJsonModel()> but does not have a IValidatable instance as a param", method.DeclaringType, method.Name))

    Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

var methods = assembly.GetTypes()
              .Where(t => t is System.Web.Mvc.Controller)
              .SelectMany(t => t.GetMethods())
              .Where(m => m.ReturnType is ActionResult)
              .Where(m => m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TargetAttribute), false).Length > 0)
              .ToArray();

bool implementsITarget = false;

foreach(method in methods)
{
    foreach(param in method.GetParameters())
    {
        if(param.ParameterType is ITarget) 
        {
            implementsITarget = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    Assert.True(implementsITarget , String.Format("Controller {0} has action {1} that does not implement ITarget but is decorated with TargetAttribute", method.DeclaringType, method.Name) );
    implementsITarget = false;
}
```

Comment: This looks very promising, thanks! A few things: I think the controller check would be better done by checking the base class, wouldn't it? eg. should inherit from the base Controller class...also, I'm not sure I'd want to ignore abstract types, as I do make use of inheritance for controllers...other than those minor details, this looks like a good solution.

Comment: @DanP: Alright, made some changes that reflect what you suggested. You are perfectly right about the Controller name check, that was me being lazy :P

Comment: This was almost exactly what I needed...the only glaring error is when comparing param is ITarget...you'll want param.ParameterType Is ITarget - great answer!

Comment: @DanP: Thanks Dan, had a real 'doh' moment when i read that :)

Comment: Yes, was certainly interesting when asserting this check...it appeared that I had failed to implement this convention for every single controller action...kind of figured there was something fishy with the logic at that point ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your auditing is a lot of trouble for a unit test that will probably not help with code quality. MVC is supposed to be better for unit testing but unit tests are not helpful. Web Forms is much better at everything else besides unit testing, so it is a better choice for enterprise applications.

Comment: Agreed, this is more of a "convention test"; it is just helpful to include it as part of a unit test suite so that my build will break if it fails as part of our CI process.